# Windows Program: How to snoop on command line arguments?

Tags: windows, command-line

I am trying to reverse engineer the build system of a commercial Windows based IDE, so I can use make to build my project.

A program is launched to perform a task, and I need to know what command line arguments are passed to this program when it is run.  However the windows process viewer does not show the command line arguments.

Is there any way to see what command line arguments are being passed when the program is launched?

(Actually it just occurred to me that I should substitute a stub program to read the command line args. Still, I'd like to know if there's an easy way).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[Sysinternals Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) lets you do that.