# Identifying Command Line Arguments

Tags: windows, reverse-engineering

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Windows Program: How to snoop on command line arguments?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1416972/windows-program-how-to-snoop-on-command-line-arguments)

I am working under Windows XP.

I've been given some third-party software that spawns several processes when launched. I've been tasked with writing a replacement for this software, though I will need to keep one of its proceeses (a "communication server" that passes / receives messages to / from identical "communication servers" on other networked machines). One small part of this process is learning to start the "communication server" directly. If I just start it with no arguments from the command line, it immediately dies. I'm thinking it needs some arguments. So, all my question boils down to is...

Is it possible, for any arbitrary process, to see what arguments it was started with? If so, how may I do so?

I tried attaching Visual Studio 2010, but there's no .pdb, so I got nothing. Unfortunately, I do not know what language this "communication server" is written in. So, it was really a longshot. (I wasn't sure if doing so would give me a way to find the arguments anyway, but I thought it was worth a try.)

Thanks,
Dave

P.S. Sorry for the poor choice of tags. This is a tough one to categorize...

Comment: If you want to do it programmically, there is some undocumented (?) API `NtQueryInformationProcess` that allows you to query the address of the PEB, that also contains the original command line (it can be read by `ReadProcessMemory`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Process Explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/de-de/sysinternals/bb896653) displays them. Right click on a process in the list, then `Properties...` -> `Image` -> `Command line`

It's not 100% reliable since the process can overwrite the buffer containing the command line, but usually it works.

Answer (score 2):

[Process explorer](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896653.aspx) will allow you to see the command line arguments for a given  running process :)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the PDB for the app itself. Windows DLLs have PDB's; put a breakpoint on `CreateProcess` and variants like `ShellExecute` / `CreateProcessAsUser`.